# Initialize User defined type attributes in PL SQL

Tags: plsql

I have pretty new to PL SQL world..and could not find an answer to my question... so here it is:

```
create or replace 
TYPE "A" as object{
school_category  varchar(10);
}

create or replace 
TYPE "B" UNDER A {
school_name varchar(10);
school_ranking INTEGER;
}
```

My Question:
1. How to initialize an object of type B, and initialize its parent's attributes?
2. Is there anyway of explicitly assigning values to attributes at the time of creating the object? for example do we have such a thing:

B_obj B := B(school_name :="example", school_ranking :="1", school_category:="elementary school");

Thanks in advance guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TYPE address_typ AS OBJECT ( 
   street          VARCHAR2(30),
   city            VARCHAR2(20),
   state           CHAR(2),
   postal_code     VARCHAR2(6) );
/
CREATE TYPE employee_typ AS OBJECT (
  employee_id       NUMBER(6),
  first_name        VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name         VARCHAR2(25),
  email             VARCHAR2(25),
  phone_number      VARCHAR2(20),
  hire_date         DATE,
  job_id            VARCHAR2(10),
  salary            NUMBER(8,2),
  commission_pct    NUMBER(2,2),
  manager_id        NUMBER(6),
  department_id     NUMBER(4),
  address           address_typ,
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER PROCEDURE display_address ( SELF IN OUT NOCOPY employee_typ ) );
/

DECLARE
  emp employee_typ; -- emp is atomically null
BEGIN
-- call the constructor for employee_typ
  emp := employee_typ(315, 'Francis', 'Logan', 'FLOGAN',
        '555.777.2222', '01-MAY-04', 'SA_MAN', 11000, .15, 101, 110, 
         address_typ('376 Mission', 'San Francisco', 'CA', '94222'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp.first_name || ' ' || emp.last_name); -- display details

END;
/
```

For more information, please refer to Oracle doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I found the article also very useful.. But I havent got my answer for the second question; is anyway to assign values to the attributes explicitly? On your example above something like that: emp := employee_typ(employee_id :=315,.....

Comment: Assignment: emp.first_name := 'Scott';